extracting the required columns from a data.table with given conditions
This is my dataset.
DTmtcars = as.data.table(mtcars); DTmtcars[, mtcarsname := rownames(mtcars)];

And these are the user input and can vary,
at least 1 will be always available which can be in any order,
these user inputs are just telling the column names of the data.table DTmtcars.
It is a sample for this question.
sometimes only column1 has a value and column2,3,4 are NA. similarly other instances could be column2 has a value and all other are NA, or column1&2 have a value and all other are NA, etc.
column1="mtcarsname";
column2="am";
column3="gear";
column4=NA;

requirement is display these columns of the dataset.
The code is an ideal solution for the sample user input above.
DTmtcars[, .(w,x,y) , env =  list(w=column1, x = column2,y =column3,z = column4)]

probably an ifelse/fifelse or any thing else to make this code dynamic so that the output is produced for all possible combinations of user input.
Output should be data.table and not a vector or concat.
code should be efficient and can be applied on a very large dataset.
I would appreciate if it can be done using data.table package only.

Your request is not clear. what do mean exactly when you say all possible combinations of user input? what is input? Add the expected output to your post.

I meant that sometimes only column1 has a value and column2,3,4 are NA. similarly other instances could be column2 has a value and all other are NA, or column1&2 have a value and all other are NA, etc.

As it seems you do not want the NA column out here is my try
library(data.table)
DTmtcars = as.data.table(mtcars); DTmtcars[, mtcarsname := rownames(mtcars)];
column1="mtcarsname";
column2="am";
column3="gear";
column4=NA;

DTmtcars[,.SD, .SDcols = na.omit(c(column1,column2,column3,column4))]

Which leads to
             mtcarsname    am  gear
                 <char> <num> <num>
 1:           Mazda RX4     1     4
 2:       Mazda RX4 Wag     1     4
 3:          Datsun 710     1     4
 4:      Hornet 4 Drive     0     3
 5:   Hornet Sportabout     0     3
 6:             Valiant     0     3
 7:          Duster 360     0     3
 8:           Merc 240D     0     4
 9:            Merc 230     0     4
10:            Merc 280     0     4
11:           Merc 280C     0     4
             ....

